# Fullcalendar Monthly events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar jQuery plugin in our page for create meeting invitation.

Am using **dow** parameter for weekly meetings . But now i want to create monthly meetings (meeting occurs once on every month of same day). Eg : If I want to create meeting on first Monday of every month. Is there any function/option available for this in fullcalendar.

Comment: Short answer is no .... you need to create and store them yourself. Or write your own logic to include them in your data

Comment: for example could have separate array of recurring events that you must add to data on every month change event

Comment: you could do it a s DOW weekly event and then use php to determine if its the first week of the month and if so - echo it in - so therefore it is a weekly event that only gets displayed once a month?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be easier than I thought to patch in monthly events and i couldnt find this anywhere so i wanted to share it.

Create a column in the database called "repeat" then repeat equals 0 is normal, 1 equals weekly, 2 equals monthly.

Then on the event rendering loop through using jQuery:

```
    var calendarData = [];
    jQuery.each(jsonData, function(index, item){
      if(item.repeat == 0){
        //normal
      }else if(item.repeat == 1){
        //use dow property
      }else if(item.repeat == 2){



 jQuery.each([-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], function(inde, ite){
      //normal but change start property
      calendarData.push({
        id:item.id
        ,type:item.type
        ,title:item.title
        ,start:moment(item.datetime).add(ite,'M').format('Y-MM-DD H:mm')
      });
    });
    }
    });
```

Then pass calendarEvents as the events for the calendar.  You can change the array of numbers to reduce or extend how long it repeats for.

(Apologies for the formatting I typed it on a tablet)